# Snowflake shows time value in UTC when data inserted using datastage

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datastage

I am using datastage as an ETL tool to insert data into Snowflake. When time value is inserting it shows a difference of 7 hours.

If actual time value is 1:00:01 then snowflake will show 6:00:01

Comment: Does the timestamp value you are inserting include a timezone component? Please add the target table definition to your answer and some sample source data. What is the timezone setting for your Snowflake account?

Comment: I am not inserting timestamp, it just time value. Data type is TIME in Snowflake. Timezone setting is America/los Angeles. Source data is time with value 01:00:07, when it is inserted into Snowflake it become 06:00:07. Datastage is connected to snowflake using jdbc

Comment: What data type are you using in Snowflake? Timestamp_ltz, Timestamp_ntz, and Timestamp_tz all behave a little differently.

Comment: How do you know it's 7 hours difference and not 5 hours difference? Can you show us the output of  **SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE '%time%'**. And also are you using Snowflake UI to see that value or another client?

Comment: Data type is TIME only, not timestamp_ntz or timestamp_ltz.

Comment: @Sergiu, I am assuming that it is converting snowflake PST time to UTC. I am using snowflake UI to see the data

Comment: @Sergiu, also all parameters values are default only. Do you have any idea about CLIENT_TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING, I am suspecting if that can be the issue. Its value is set to TIMESTAMP_LTZ.

Comment: @MohitaVerma Can you make a quick test by inserting the value via Snowflake UI? Does it still shows a difference? CLIENT_TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING is defaulting to TIMESTAMP_LTZ and applies only to JDBC/ODBC connectors. Are you inserting using one of these connectors?

Comment: Hi @Sergiu, I did try and I don't see any change in time when inserted using snowflake UI. I am using JDBC connector (datastage 11.7)  to put data in snowflake.

Comment: @Sergiu, I also changed CLIENT_TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING  = timestamp_ntz at user level and tried loading the data, but not luck

Comment: Have you set maybe [JDBC_USE_SESSION_TIMEZONE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#jdbc-use-session-timezone) to FALSE?

Comment: No @Sergiu, all parameters are set to default only

Comment: @MohitaVerma I don't have Datastage, but using a simple Java class and inserting a time value shows me the correct value in the UI. I am not able to reproduce your issue so I am thinking it might be related to some settings or the way Datastage works. Are you able to test outside of Datastage with a simple Java class?

Comment: Hi @Sergiu, not with java, but I tried with Python using same snowflake jdbc connector and it is giving same output. Whatever I inserted same I can see in snowflake also. When I try to unload data to a file using Datastage it is giving correct res

Comment: @MohitaVerma What version of JDBC are you using?

Comment: hi @Sergiu, I am using JDBC 3.12.6

Comment: Hi @MohitaVerma Can you use latest version of the driver (3.13.4) and let us know if you still have the issue? There were some issues fixed in 3.13.2 with respect to getTime method.